# Is it possible to limit delivery of mail to select user mailboxes to specific hours in Postfix?

Tags: postfix

In an attempt to enforce company hours and lessen employee stress, I would like to limit the delivery of email to their user mailboxes to business hours while not limiting outbound or normal mail receipt by our servers.

I know that MS Exchange offers something like this, but we are an all Linux/FreeBSD shop and use postfix as our mail server.

Comment: Well, the first thing that comes to mind is to start and stop the pop3/imap service via cron job. The mails would be delivered to the mailbox, but the user can't retrieve them during out of office hours.

Comment: Thanks, Gerald, but I only want this to affect specific users.  For instance, the engineering and support teams communicate almost 24x7, so they should not be affected.  I just want others (finance/accounting, HR, marketing, etc.), to be able to relax through their weekends and holidays without stress that comes with an email that arrives at 5:15P on Friday since they can't do anything until Monday, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

IMAP servers provide filtering & access control that can be used to "hide" the mail, while leaving delivery almost untouched.

During all hours stash away mails you do not want to see work done on (example code for global sieve filtering, works with dovecot):

```
if allof(
  anyof(
    envelope :is "To" "will.rested@ourcompany.example",
    envelope :is "To" "sheila.sleepwell@ourcompany.example"
  ),
  not anyof (
    envelope :matches "From" "MAILER-DAEMON",
    address :domain "From" "ourcompany.example",
    address :domain "From" "emergencyservice.example"
  )
  anyof (
    date :zone "-0500" :is "received" "weekday" "6",
    allof(date :zone "-0500" :is "received" "weekday" "5",
          date :zone "-0500" :value "gt" "received" "hour" "21")
  )
) {
   fileinto :create "Embargo";
   stop;
}
```

During office hours move mail from the Embargo folder to the INBOX (example for dovecot):

```
$ cat /etc/cron.hourly/disembark
is_work_day || exit 0
doveadm -u "will.rested@ourcompany.example" move INBOX mailbox Embargo
doveadm -u "sheila.sleepwell@ourcompany.example" move INBOX mailbox Embargo
```

You can then deny access to the Embargo mailbox (example for dovecot acl).

```
$ cat /mail/gobal.acl
Embargo anyone
```

I would recommend leaving out the last step.
Not subscribing the "Embargo" mailbox should be entirely sufficient to effect a nudge into the right direction, while not creating strong incentives to work around the measure, should special circumstances require receiving mail during unusual office time.

**Caveats**:

- it is a technical solution to non-technical problem: expect underwhelming results

  - the name of the measure might have great effect on how it is perceived
  - e.g. embargo, anti-stress, resting
- you probably need to think about (office, mail server) time zones before implementing

  - sieve saves you the headache, other mail filtering may not be so generous
- simple move will break existing mail sorting

  - `sieve-refilter` might do the trick, but is not well tested for such purpose

Comment: Interesting manner of dealing with this.  Because the users involved are all local, timezones aren't an issue.  We'll need to add dovecot to the arsenal, but it's a great starting place.

Comment: @Timpraetor i do not think you do. Its just the method by which i access my mail - whatever IMAP server you have in place can probably do the same thing.